# How to position a collection on a surface

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image]How to position a collection on a surface, changing only the position on the Z-axis

Comment: rigid body, geometry nodes, animation nodes....and i know some add-ons can do this as well

Comment: Do you want the bottoms of the objects in the collection to sit on the surface? Are they always spheres?

Comment: @Robin Betts, yes move only along the Z axis of the sphere to the surface